Why does my ESC/POS printer stop responding after attempting to print a QR code?
I am using the following function to send ESC/POS commands to my printer. The function works perfectly for printing styled text, but when I try to print a QR code, the printer does not respond.
After calling this function to print a QR code, the printer becomes unresponsive to all subsequent print commands (text or QR code) until it is power-cycled.
Here is the code:
bool Printer::sendToPrinter(const std::string &devicePath, const std::string &text) {
    std::string qrCodeCommands =
            "\x1B\x40"
            "\x1D\x28\x6B\x04\x00\x31\x41\x32\x00"
            "\x1D\x28\x6B\x03\x00\x31\x43\x03"
            "\x1D\x28\x6B\x03\x00\x31\x45\x31"
            "\x1D\x28\x6B\x0F\x00\x31\x50\x30"
            "Hello world"
            "\x1D\x28\x6B\x03\x00\x31\x51\x30";

    std::string processedText = "\x1B\x40" + qrCodeCommands + "\n\n";

#ifdef _WIN32
    HANDLE hPrinter = CreateFile(devicePath.c_str(), GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hPrinter == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        log("Failed to open printer device: " + devicePath);
        return false;
    }

    DWORD bytesWritten = 0;
    if (!WriteFile(hPrinter, processedText.c_str(), processedText.size(), &bytesWritten, NULL)) {
        log("Failed to send data to printer.");
        CloseHandle(hPrinter);
        return false;
    }

    if (bytesWritten != processedText.size()) {
        log("Mismatch in bytes written to printer.");
        CloseHandle(hPrinter);
        return false;
    }

    CloseHandle(hPrinter);
#else
    const int fd = open(devicePath.c_str(), O_WRONLY);
    if (fd < 0) {
        log("Failed to open printer device: " + devicePath);
        return false;
    }

    ssize_t bytesWritten = write(fd, processedText.c_str(), processedText.size());
    if (bytesWritten < 0) {
        log("Failed to send data to printer.");
        close(fd);
        return false;
    }

    if (bytesWritten != static_cast<ssize_t>(processedText.size())) {
        log("Mismatch in bytes written to printer.");
        close(fd);
        return false;
    }

    close(fd);
#endif

    log("Data successfully sent to printer: " + text);
    return true;
}

Text printing works fine when I call this function with plain text or styled text, but as soon as I use it to print a QR code with the ESC/POS commands above, the printer stops responding.
I have verified the ESC/POS commands against the documentation from Epson's ESC/POS reference guide.
I also tried transforming the content into hex values, but the result was the same.
What could be causing the printer to hang after sending the QR code commands? How can I fix this issue?

Since the length of the data "Hello world" is probably 10 bytes, surely the length of the QR data store command should be \x0D, not \x0F?

I changed the size, and still, the same problem occurred where the printer was not responding to anything after these commands were sent.

A \x00 in a C-string literal terminates the C-string literal.  That's probably causing some grief.

Hmm, strange, because I have command {R"({{{/b}}})", "\x1B\x45\x00"} in another function and it works as expected (turn of bold text).
